# Android ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem with my android app. The app is in the store and I am working on an update. I am using internal file storage for persisting user data. On testing the beta the I get - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pea.jay.wiskey.c.e

I do not have any packages or classes named 'e' or 'c'.

I have spent many hours researching and troubleshooting with no luck. I tried switching pro guard off/on, rebuilding and cleaning the project, deleting build folder.

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Full stack trace here -

```
01-30 22:20:43.306 11211-11211/? W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pea.jay.wiskey.c.e
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2263)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.persistance.InternalStorage.readObject(InternalStorage.java:121)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.persistance.InternalStorage.testObjectExists(InternalStorage.java:32)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.persistance.InternalStorage.getAllLists(InternalStorage.java:94)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.persistance.GlobalListHolder.<init>(GlobalListHolder.java:24)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.persistance.GlobalListHolder.getInstance(GlobalListHolder.java:37)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.pea.jay.wiskey.userInterface.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:154)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
01-30 22:20:43.308 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pea.jay.wiskey.c.e" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pea.jay.wiskey-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:  ... 37 more
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pea.jay.wiskey.c.e
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:      ... 38 more
01-30 22:20:43.309 11211-11211/? W/System.err:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: I guess that you are using proguard and saving obfuscated class with ObjectOutputStream ... in new version obfuscation change ... So now your  whole internal storage is useless ... to avoid it in the future do not obfuscate class which you are saving with ObjectOutputStream ...

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense, I will exclude the persisted classes from proguard. Guess my user's data will be wiped on update.